# C# Winforms - add embedded resource that is editable when published?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, embedded-resource

I have created a document creation tool that populates macros which are located inside a .docx file.

Of course, if I send my program to someone, they won't have the docx file on their machine.

I can embed the docx file as an embedded resource, but I also want the docx file to be editable.

Is there a way to accomplish this using the Visual Studio Installer?

Comment: Why can't you just add the docx file as an additional file for the installer to put in the application's directory?

Comment: @VisualVincent, yes, I had thought of that last night. Thanks for the suggestion!